Manga or manhwa with a chosen hero who gets cheated on by his fiancée and becomes a powerful demon lord
The chosen hero has been groomed to save the kingdom. His fiancée and best friend travel with him, fighting hordes of Foes. The girl gets lonely. The friend mocks the hero. They hook up and the hero sees them. Somehow he pushes through and faces the demon lord, who is female. They hook up and he becomes a powerful demon lord.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Hey Logic, it was black and white.

Did the story show the actual sex scenes?

Yes, I think it was a manwha, with those long ass names

Was the friend you mentioned a big muscular guy, older looking than the main character?

Yes, exactly. It wasn't a huge disparity in age but you're definitely onto something. The black and white implied the friend was darker skinned, taller, and with a light colored, almost boxy hair style

Is this The End of the Line for the Cuckold Hero...? It's a one-shot hentai doujin with explicit sex scenes. I struggled to find a suitable page to link to, but hopefully this WebNovel page should be okay.

During his journey to defeat the demon king, Harry discovers the horrible betrayal of his childhood friend and love Miria who is having an affair with his other companion Carlos due to his own neglect. After being abandoned by the two so that they could have their baby, in madness and despair he storms the demon lords castle and becomes the new demon king, his revenge has only just begun.

The main character, Harry, is a Hero on a journey to defeat the Demon Lord with two companions; his childhood friend, Miria, and a guy named Carlos. The story begins with all three in a battlefield littered with dead demons, and Miria tending to Harry and Carlos' wounds. During this scene, Harry effectively proposes marriage to Miria, without fully saying all the words.
Harry is portrayed as a relatively virtuous guy who believes he must stay focused on defeating the Demon Lord before consummating his relationship with Miria, whereas Carlos is openly lustful, unabashedly having sex with other women and clearly eyeing up Miria as well.
Harry subsequently sees Carlos and Miria having sex and concludes that this has been going on behind his back all along, but doesn't reveal his presence to them and continues travelling with them to the Demon Lord's castle.
When they get there, Harry wants to go straight in, but Carlos says they should head back to town to rest and resupply first, since they're tired and low on items. When Harry says they can't turn back now, Carlos insists that he and Miria are heading back and reveals that Miria is pregnant with his child. They walk off and leave Harry to confront the Demon Lord alone.
Incensed, Harry storms the Demon Lord's castle on his own and hacks and slashes his way through numerous demons, but when he reaches the throne room he hesitates upon seeing that the Demon Lord is beautiful young woman sitting passively on her throne. She seduces him into having sex with her and by the end of the story, he's sat on the throne as the new Demon Lord, while the kingdom he came from has been overrun by his army.

Bingo!! Great synopsis, whoever wrote that.

@Achilles Lionheart - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.
